# should i choose venv folder as vs code workspace folder on prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-venv

sequence of steps:

- created a folder
- init it as vscode workspace:created code-workspace file
- python -m venv myproject_env

then vscode prompts me:

> We noticed a new environment has been created. Do you want to select
> it for the workspace folder?

should i init the entire vscode wokrspace again in that folder? what is the difference?

Comment: it means do you want to use the Python interpreter in this virt env for this workspace

Comment: @rioV8, but i just created virt env and gave it a name - this means the python interpreter will be the standard?

Comment: no, you just add a new python interpreter to the set of found interpreters, you still have to select one, and VSC suggests to use the new created one